# Geolocation Push Notifications

Tags: notifications, geolocation, push

I'm using phonegap/cordova for both my iOS and Android applications. I'm looking for geolocation push notifications, so I can do a push message for both my east coast and west coast customers. Is there a third party platform that would allow me to integrate this ability and let me do one-time push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

We recently did the same thing.

Initially:

We tried to capture all the user push ids and store them, then set our own system up. Which was a pain in the...

Then:

A better option is to set up native push notifications with http://parse.com/

They have a few API options. So its easy to set up the users.

- When you add the user
- also add a [channel]
- Call the channel ["east_coast"] or ["west_coast"]

Then push a notification out to the channels that include ["east_coast"]

Easy.